# The multi-part identifier could not be bound in ms sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I wrote a SQL server query with three table left outer joins and it executed well in SQL SERVER console.

**Here is the query**

```
select  [a].[audittraceid],  
 [a].[description], 
 [a].[remarks],  
 [a].[ip],  
 [a].[oldvalue],  
 [a].[newvalue],  
 [a].[lastupdateduser],  
 convert(varchar(19),[a].[lastupdatedtime],120) as lastupdatedtime,  
 convert(varchar(19),[a].[createdtime],120) as createdtime, 
 [a].[affectedkey],  
 [ur].[userrolecode] as userrolecode,  
 [ur].[description] as userroledes, 
 [p].[pagecode] as pagecode, 
 [p].[description] as pagedes,  
 [t].[description] as taskdes  
 From [TESTDB].[dbo].[Audittrace] [a] 
 left outer join [TESTDB].[dbo].[Userrole] [ur] on [a].[userrolecode]=[ur].[userrolecode]  
 left outer join [TESTDB].[dbo].[Page] [p] on [a].[pagecode]=[p].[pagecode]  
 left outer join [TESTDB].[dbo].[Task] [t] on [a].[taskcode]=[t].[taskcode]
 order by [a].[lastupdatedtime] desc
```

But when I use this query with my application which uses hibernate, hibernate change the query as below.

```
WITH query AS (
    SELECT inner_query.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as __hibernate_row_nr__ FROM ( 
        select TOP(10)  [a].[audittraceid] as page0_, 
        [a].[description] as page1_,  
        [a].[remarks] as page2_,  
        [a].[ip] as page3_,  
        [a].[oldvalue] as page4_,  
        [a].[newvalue] as page5_,  
        [a].[lastupdateduser] as page6_,  
        convert(varchar(19),[a].[lastupdatedtime],120) as lastupdatedtime,  
        convert(varchar(19),[a].[createdtime],120) as createdtime,  
        [a].[affectedkey] as page7_,  [ur].[userrolecode] as userrolecode,  
        [ur].[description] as userroledes,  [p].[pagecode] as pagecode,  
        [p].[description] as pagedes,  
        [t].[description] as taskdes  From [BIMPUTHDEV01].[dbo].[Audittrace] [a] 
        left outer join [TESTDB].[dbo].[Userrole] [ur] on [a].[userrolecode]=[ur].[userrolecode]  
        left outer join [TESTDB].[dbo].[Page] [p] on [a].[pagecode]=[p].[pagecode]  
        left outer join [TESTDB].[dbo].[Task] [t] on [a].[taskcode]=[t].[taskcode]   
        order by [a].[lastupdatedtime] desc 
    ) inner_query 
) 
SELECT 
page0_, 
page1_, 
page2_, 
page3_, 
page4_, 
page5_, 
page6_, 
lastupdatedtime, 
createdtime, 
page7_, 
userrolecode, 
userroledes, 
pagecode,  
[p].[description] as pagedes,  /*This line gives the error*/
[t].[description] as taskdes   
FROM query
```

In this changed **Hibernate query** gives me following error when running the application.

- The multi-part identifier "p.description" could not be bound.
- org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: The multi-part
  identifier "p.description" could not be bound.
- Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The
  multi-part identifier "p.description" could not be bound.

I found same type of questions in stack overflow , but didn't find any correct answer for issue.

Is any one can describe why it happen and how to fix this issue it will be great helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

In my hibernate configuration file **previously** i added hibernate dialect property as below.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect</property>
```

But it was wrong.

I change the hibernate dialect property as below.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
```

This works fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

can you try and do this with a native query instead? as shown below?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Employee.class);
List results = query.list();
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your corporation.